# dashDB local MPP deployment issue - cannot connect to database

Tags: docker, dashdb

I am facing a huge problem at deploying a dashDB local cluster. After a successful deployment the following error comes in case of trying to create a single table or launch a query. Furthermore webserver is not working properly like in previous SMP deployment.

> Cannot connect to database "BLUDB" on node "20" because the difference
>   between the system time on the catalog node and the virtual timestamp
>   on this node is greater than the max_time_diff database manager
>   configuration parameter.. SQLCODE=-1472, SQLSTATE=08004,
>   DRIVER=4.18.60

I followed official deployment guide, so followings were doublechecked:

- each physical machines' and docker containers' /etc/hosts file contains all ips, fully qualified and simple hostnames
- there is a NFS preconfigured and mounted to /mnt/clusterfs on every single server
- none of the servers signed an error at phase "docker logs --follow dashDB" command
- nodes config file is located in /mnt/clusterfs directory

After starting dashDB with following command:

```
docker exec -it dashDB start
```

It looks as it should be (see below), but the error can be found at [/opt/ibm/dsserver/logs/dsserver.0.log](https://ibm.box.com/s/n64g7xocwok8i5qssdekif2nwvq3j1o1).

> #
>   
>   --- dashDB stack service status summary ---
>   
>   ##################################################################### Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  slapd.service
>
> SUMMARY
>
> LDAPrunning: SUCCESS 
>   dashDBtablesOnline: SUCCESS 
>   WebConsole : SUCCESS 
>   dashDBconnectivity : SUCCESS 
>   dashDBrunning : SUCCESS
>
> #
>   
>   --- dashDB high availability status ---
>   
>   #
>
> Configuring dashDB high availability ... Stopping the system Stopping
>   datanode dashdb02 Stopping datanode dashdb01 Stopping headnode
>   dashdb03 Running sm on head node dashdb03 .. Running sm on data node
>   dashdb02 .. Running sm on data node dashdb01 .. Attempting to activate
>   previously failed nodes, if any ... SM is RUNNING on headnode dashdb03
>   (ACTIVE) SM is RUNNING on datanode dashdb02 (ACTIVE) SM is RUNNING on
>   datanode dashdb01 (ACTIVE) Overall status : RUNNING

After several redeployment nothing has changed. Please help me in what I am doing wrong.

Many Thanks, Daniel

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear -- time is out of sync between containers. Make sure ntp is running in each one and can connect to a reliable source.

Comment: @mustaccio thank you! The problem was that I had launched docker containers and only later enabled and started ntp service, so it had no effect on containers' date & time.

Answer (score 0):

Always make sure to NTP service is started on every single cluster node before starting a docker container. Otherwise it will take no effect on it.